# plus sign doesnt move up or down

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been trying to move this span (+  sign) down a bit so that it's in line with the question, been trying margin, padding top or bottom, but nothing works. tried removing the other padding from parent classes still didn't work. can anyone spot my mistake, thanks :)

```js
(function($) {
    $(function() {
        $('.faqs dt').click(function () {
            $(this).children('.plusminus').text($(this).children('.plusminus').text() == '+' ? '−' : '+');
            $(this).next('.faqs dd').slideToggle(500);
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
    .faqs {
      cursor: pointer;
      border: #edeceb solid 1px;
      border-radius: 3px;
      margin: 20px 0;
      padding: 30px 35px 10px;
      line-height: 200%;
      }
      dt{
        font-size: 1.125rem;
        font-weight: 700;
        margin-top: -20px;}
      .plusminus{
        font-weight: 100;
        font-size: xxx-large;
      }
      .answer{
        display: none;
        margin: 10px 0;
      }
      .date{
        color: #a6a6a6;
        font-size: 0.750rem;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab--container">
  <div class="tab--content">
  <div class="content--faqs">
    <div class="content--title">
    Q&A
    </div>
    <dl class="faqs">
    <dt><span class="plusminus">+</span> Question 1?</dt>
    <dd class="answer">Answer 1.<br>
    <div class="date">
    Answer date.
    </div></dd>
    </dl>
    <dl class="faqs">
    <dt><span class="plusminus">+</span> Question 2?</dt>
    <dd class="answer">Answer 2.<br>
    <div class="date">
     Answer date.
    </div></dd>
    </dl>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of my favourite challenges. It was an issue of the `line-height` and so on. I added these:

```css
.plusminus {
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: xxx-large;
  line-height: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 0.15em;
}
```

Hope this gives you what's the reason.

Preview

[image: preview]

Here's the full code:

```js
(function($) {
  $(function() {
    $('.faqs dt').click(function() {
      $(this).children('.plusminus').text($(this).children('.plusminus').text() == '+' ? '−' : '+');
      $(this).next('.faqs dd').slideToggle(500);
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.faqs {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: #edeceb solid 1px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 20px 0;
  padding: 30px 35px 10px;
  line-height: 200%;
}

dt {
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-top: -20px;
}

.plusminus {
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: xxx-large;
  line-height: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 0.15em;
}

.answer {
  display: none;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.date {
  color: #a6a6a6;
  font-size: 0.750rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab--container">
  <div class="tab--content">
    <div class="content--faqs">
      <div class="content--title">
        Q&A
      </div>
      <dl class="faqs">
        <dt><span class="plusminus">+</span> Question 1?</dt>
        <dd class="answer">Answer 2.<br>
          <div class="date">
            Answer date.
          </div>
        </dd>
      </dl>
      <dl class="faqs">
        <dt><span class="plusminus">+</span> Question 2?</dt>
        <dd class="answer">Answer 2.<br>
          <div class="date">
            Answer date.
          </div>
        </dd>
      </dl>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Praven Thank you for the answer, sinse u love challenges i will show you what that looks like in a real website, The new Challenge that gave me a headache is the following:
the plus sign jumps about 0.1px upwards when i open the question.
dont know what causes it, here is a link to the website, just scroll  all the way down down, when u click the question u will notice the minus sign gets smaller and goes up a bit. do you think using element inspection will reveal why thats happening ? or should i be going through codes ? http://superpatronen.c-962.maxcluster.net/brother-mfc-9340-cdw

Comment: @Zyfella Oh no. I'll check it out now... Give me some time.

Comment: @Zyfella The site doesn't seem to open in my network. I am in the UK. Does this matter anyway for opening the site?

Comment: oh, well I guess unlucky, the website is a shopware site that I'm working on, I don't really know why u don't have access as it should be accessible in and outside of the EU, I just couldn't understand why the the sign shifts when i implement it. i looked through all the classes but nothing changed, aynways thank you very much for the effort. :)

Comment: Ohhh okay... I'll try to figure out if there's a way I can help. Can you repro the issue in CodeSandbox or something please?

Comment: sry for the late answer, that day i tried to inser and copy all elements from the website into js.fiddle and it worked fine there aswell. dont know why its not reacting the same on the website but i will let you know when i figure it out ;) here is the link https://jsfiddle.net/5p0nh7aL/3/

Comment: @Zyfella Checking it now.

Comment: @Zyfella Yea, I couldn't see any jump on the page. And yes, if I get access to the real page - maybe there are other styles that are acting upon it. Thanks for the efforts too. 

Comment: i finally fixed it but had to take a different path, couldnt use + or - withing the <span> as a text so i used <span>&#8330;</span> and <span>&#8331;</span>
, gave each an id  then used toggle to display them , now they work fine and stay in the same place.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the flexbox property to move this span (+ sign) down a bit so that it's in line with the question,

```js
(function($) {
    $(function() {
        $('.faqs dt').click(function () {
            $(this).children('.plusminus').text($(this).children('.plusminus').text() == '+' ? '−' : '+');
            $(this).next('.faqs dd').slideToggle(500);
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
 .faqs {
      cursor: pointer;
      border: #edeceb solid 1px;
      border-radius: 3px;
      margin: 20px 0;
      padding: 30px 35px 10px;
      line-height: 200%;
      }
      dt{
        display: flex;
        font-size: 1.125rem;
        font-weight: 700;
        margin-top: -20px;}
      .plusminus{
        font-weight: 100;
        font-size: xxx-large;
      }
      .answer{
        display: none;
        margin: 10px 0;
      }
      .date{
        color: #a6a6a6;
        font-size: 0.750rem;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab--container">
  <div class="tab--content">
  <div class="content--faqs">
    <div class="content--title">
    Q&A
    </div>
    <dl class="faqs">
    <dt><span class="plusminus">+</span> Question 1?</dt>
    <dd class="answer">Answer 2.<br>
    <div class="date">
    Answer date.
    </div></dd>
    </dl>
    <dl class="faqs">
    <dt><span class="plusminus">+</span> Question 2?</dt>
    <dd class="answer">Answer 2.<br>
    <div class="date">
     Answer date.
    </div></dd>
    </dl>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

its because of font-size you given to the `plusminus` insted of this you can give the font-size to its `parent class`.